# How to fix this > attribute app:constraintBottom_toBottomOf not found

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Android newbie here.

I am building and AR app and now I'm planning to add a User Interface. I am trying to add a constraint layout to `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`, however Im getting the error that this constraint was not found

These are my codes and error messages:

[image: code and error]
[image: more of error]

All the lines of code I add in my activity_ux.xml file that begin with "app"
e.g. `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf` do not seem to work, I just showed you an example here with one of them just to make it easier to debug I think.

I tried searching online, one of the solutions was that I should install "ConstraintLayout for Android" and "Solver for ConstraintLayout" in my SDK Tools, but I already had this installed.

```
    <FrameLayout 
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          tools:context="com.google.ar.sceneform.Overlei.Overlei">

    <fragment android:name="com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment"
          android:id="@+id/ux_fragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/gallery_layout"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
  >

   </LinearLayout>

   </FrameLayout>
```

I expected this to just work, I don't know where I can start looking if an in-built function(such as this) does not work.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions guys. I have managed to deal with the error by adding this line

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
```

into my `build.gradle(module.app)` under `dependencies`

Again, thanks for everything

Comment: I have added `implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'`, and my issue got fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf` only in `ConstraintLayout`. You can try to use inside of `FrameLayout`
then `android:gravity = "bottom"` in your LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap you FrameLayout in a ConstraintLayout or change the FrameLayout to ConstraintLayout

Answer (score 0):

In an flutter plugin I was developing, I got the same issue and it got fixed by adding the following line in plugin's `build gradle` as a `dependency`.

`implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'`