# "layout_constraintBottom_totopOf" not found

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

On rebuilding the project,I get an error like this

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: attribute layout_constraintBottom_totopOf (aka com.example.seve:layout_constraintBottom_totopOf) not found.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\hack1\\IntelliJIDEAProjects\\Seve\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\layout_screen.xml","position":{"startLine":10}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
```

I went to `layout_screen.xml` and saw nothing useful on line 10 of the xml file.
If anyone could help me what `"startLine":10`actually mean.It would be of great use.

Here is my `layout_screen.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                                   android:background="#fff"
                                                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                   android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                android:id="@+id/guideline"
                                                app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="392dp"
                                                android:orientation="horizontal"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_totopOf="@+id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
            android:id="@+id/intro_title"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.049"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="16dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/intro_description"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/intro_title"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[5]"
            android:id="@+id/intro_img"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/intro_title"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I expect the project to build successfully but i am not able to find the error on line 10 or maybe i am looking on the wrong line.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55403102/7666442

Comment: Tried that, same error..btw thanx @NileshRathod

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the error comme from "totopOf" that's must have a uppercase T ==>
app:layout_constraintBottom_**toTopOf**="@+id/guideline"

Comment: Thanx Sebastien that worked, it didn't worked at first try but as i restarted it ..it worked!Thank you

Comment: another thing, you should remove all you marginLeft marginRight and replace all of them by marginStart and margingEnd. you duplicated this margins in you xml but it's a mistake.

android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" == android:layout_marginStart="8dp" 
android:layout_marginRight="8dp" == android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"

Comment: Done! thanx saviour sebastien

Comment: having both marginStart  and marginLeft is not a mistake its sometime needed for mobiles of API < 17..so one will be ignored in favour of the other depending of the API level

Comment: why do you put the + in  app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"

Answer (score 5):

ConstraintLayout is not part of AppCompat. It's a standalone library.

Add the dependency in your build.gradle file

implementation `'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'` and click Sync now.

Comment: Thanx dude, but i already have consraintlayout on my build.gradle as ```implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'```