# Creating an Android launchscreen xml in Flutter project using constraint layout - constraints not found

Tags: android, flutter

I wanted to create a new Android launch screen for my Flutter app using constraint layout.

Firstly, I wasn't able to directly open layout builder in Android Studio in my Flutter app project. So using Android Studio, I created a new Android app with an empty activity and used the layout builder to create my layout by setting constraints. I then copied the generated XML into `launch_background.xml` of my Flutter project - where my previous splashscreen (not using constraint layout) had been working. I added this `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` in the `android.defaultConfig` in and `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'` in dependencies, both in `build.gradle`.

I'm now unable to run my app because of errors for each constraint:

`attribute layout_constraintTop_toTopOf (aka pha.myapp.dep.us:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf) not found.`

...and repeat for each constraint.

**How have I already tried to fix it?**

- I tried with this:  `implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'` in the
  dependencies in `build.gradle` but my app was stuck building for over
  an hour.
- I've run `flutter clean`
- I've deleted my entire `gradle` file.

Am I missing something?

Finally, as reference, this is my XML file. The three drawables exist and have worked before when I haven't used constraint layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
   >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_bg_splash" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="157dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="157dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="157dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="157dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="56dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_brandlogotag" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55403102/how-to-fix-this-attribute-appconstraintbottom-tobottomof-not-found